# How to start with linkedIn API?

Tags: python

Being new to API, I am currently trying to use linkedIn information for my application. For that I'm using [python-linkedin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin/4.0) interface for accessing linkedIn API. I installed this module by using following command:

`pip install python-linkedin`.

I have written one sample python file to use this interface as:

```
from linkedin import linkedin  
API_KEY = "api-key"  
API_SECRET = "api-secret"  
RETURN_URL = "http://localhost:8000"  
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())  
print authentication.authorization_url   
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

I got the following output-

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?scope=r_basicprofile%20rw_nus%20r_network%20r_contactinfo%20w_messages%20rw_groups%20r_emailaddress%20r_fullprofile&state=8a9678902396c6e7f7e0027a486898d2&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost%3A8000&response_type=code&client_id=api-key

I want to integrate this with my application. And I need to fetch data from linkedIn and store it in database. Does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback url should be externally accessible. using localhost is not valid url. instead try to use your external IP address.